# Text won't align at top of box

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, formatting

I have two text boxes. One is aligned directly at the top of the box, the other has a space at the top. They have the exact same settings; I cannot find any difference between them.

What is causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of things can cause this.
Showing the hidden characters may help.

[image: Extra break character, or break has wrong font size,]